# UITypeEditor in DropDown: How do i change the location of the dropdown?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I have a custom UITypeEditor that drops down a screen thats... larger than average... (about 500x500px).  However, it doesn't seem like the dropdown is intelligent enough to dropdown int he right location correctly (see the screenshot below).  Do I have any options here besides re-rerolling my UITypeEditor as a dialog?

Thanks!

[image: The dialog runs to the top of the screen]

Comment: How are you showing the drop down? Are you using IWindowsFormsEditorService.DropDownControl?

Comment: I subclassed NVHViewerCollection.  Set GetEditStyle to Dropdown, and am using  es.DropDownControl(thisControl); in EditValue

Comment: Then can't you can resize the control before showing it? or hook on events on the control, and resize it after shown?

Comment: I could resize it.  The whole point of the question is that there IS enough room if the dropdown just... dropped down.  Instead its showing above the dropdown glyph, and running off the top of the screen.

Comment: There is no option for this as the property grid does some "clever" and automagic computation before showing the control. Usually it works well (including cases where the grid is near screen edges). For some reason, it can't compute properly size and pos in your case, probably because of something you do (directly or indirectly) in your code. you can study the internals of the DropDownControl code here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/PropertyGridView.cs#d7c3fee8268d98c7

Comment: Thanks for the link, i'll investigate